# perform block wavelet transform on an image

Tags: matlab, image-processing, wavelet-transform

I want to localize spatial frequency measure that relates depth to image by performing a block (16x16) wavelet transform that will output 256 wavelet coefficients.

I'm not sure how to perform the wavelet transform on blocks instead of the whole image. I tried:

```
f = @(x) wavedec2(x.data,2,'db1');
J = blockproc(gI,[N, N],f);
```

But it doesn't work correctly.

So I tried to perform the wavelet transfrom on the whole image:

```
I = imread('input.jpg');
I = im2double(I);
gI = rgb2gray(I);
[C, S]= wavedec2(gI,2,'db1'); % Perform wavelet decomposition 
D = detcoef2('h',C,S,1); %Extract details coefficients
```

However, I'm not sure how to get a count of only the high and low frequency coefficient in each block.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to perform a block wavelet transform on your image:

```
N = 32; % block size 16x16
A = mat2cell(gI, repmat(N,[1 size(gI,1)/N]),...
repmat(N,[1 size(gI,2)/N]));
[LL, LH, HL, HH] = cellfun(@(X) dwt2(X,'haar'),A, ...
'UniformOutput',false);
 LL_final = cell2mat(LL);
 LH_final = cell2mat(LH);
 HL_final = cell2mat(HL);
 HH_final = cell2mat(HH);
```

Comment: It works! Thank you. But how can I get only the high and low frequency coefficients in each block?